# WCF Data Service Run Time EDMX

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

What I am looking may not be readily available.  If so please let me know.

Have an application where a users in a role can dynamically add fields.  Fields are used to classify documents.

For string just have a single (static schema) table with pk as rowID, fieldID and a non-key field of value.  For example fieldID = 1 is Subject and fieldID = 2 is Author.   So can add user fields with no change to the database schema.  Subject = Mapping maps to TSQL (fieldID=1 and Value='Mapping')

The primary interface is a UI but also have a button to export the search results (rows of fields) to XML.  It is popular and would like to extend that to on ODATA type access.

Would like to add a WCF Data Service but expose the entity with properties Subject and Author and ....  Read about EntityObject Generator but it appears need to update the reference.  What I need is the EDMX to be built and read at run time and then a facility to map Subject="Mapping" to (fieldID=1 and value="Mapping").

Hopefully I have described what I am looking for.  Not looking for a prescriptive type answer.  More like this tool should get you there or a no it just does not work that way.

I don't know much about ODATA or WCF Data Service but if it looks like there is a way to make this work I will learn it .

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you model the fields as a related table (as you seem to have already), and the schema of the DB doesn't change, then you don't need to generate EDMX on the fly. Just generate it against the static schema. Or maybe I don't understand what you want the OData endpoint to look like.

Comment: @VitekKarasMSFT Please tell me more about related table.  I have not done that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's not important. The important part is that you say your DB schema is static, so why do you think you need to generate EDMX dynamically?

Comment: @VitekKarasMSFT Because that static schema (docID, fieldID, value) to too much for (my) users to consume.  Via fieldID that single table holds multiple fields. Assume Subject is fieldID=1.  Search fieldID=1 and value=Houston is a no go.  Report back the data as fieldID=1 value=Houston is a no go.  I want an ODATA interface of Subject=Houston and shield the user from fieldID.  Through fieldID new fields are added run time.  Thanks

Comment: Got it - in that case though you can't use EF since it doesn't support such mapping. You would have to implement a custom provider: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx specifically the part 9 about untyped providers since you probably don't want to generate new CLR types every time a user adds a field.

Comment: @VitekKarasMSFT That was my questions. Custom Data Service Providers is what I will look at.  Please post as an answer so that I can accept and and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems the requirement is to generate entities with dynamic properties based on the fields rows in the DB, this can't be done using the built-in EF or Reflection providers (since both rely on having statically defined CLR types to define the entities).

The way to solve this is to implement a custom provider as described in this blog series: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx
Namely the un-typed custom provider.

Comment: That article had no code samples and it recommend the 5.0 SDK as it had code sample.  But I installed the 5.0 SDK and cannot find any code samples. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29306

Comment: The sample code for a custom provider (even untyped) is part of the OData Provider Toolkit which can be downloaded here: http://www.odata.org/ecosystem#samplecode.